# Replacing code between two JavaScript comments

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I need to set a value of JavaScript variable from bash. Variable lives in index.html file and I'd like to use unix SED command to do that. Inside index.html I have it lake this:

```
<script>
/*bash_var*/ var foo = 1;  /*end_bash_var*/
</script>
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
sed -i -e 's%/*bash_var*/(.*)/*end_bash_var*//'"$ var foo = 0; /g" index.html
```

and few more variations of this command, but I alway get some error.

Comment: `sed '\|/\*bash_var\*/.*foo.*/\*end_bash_var\*/|s|= .\+;|= 0;|`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i ':/*bash_var*/:,:/*end_bash_var*/: { s|=.+;|= 0;|; }' index.html
```

This `sed` command replaces the value presented between `=` and `;` (`=.*;`) with `0` which that is between both `/*bash_var*/` and `/*end_bash_var*/` in `index.html`